# shopt -s extglob not working

Tags: bash, wildcard

I am running my script on distant server. Here is header of my .sh script:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob; 
#turns on extended globbing features ('!' can then be used to exclude file names)

echo `ls -la /storage/brno2/home/nicki/snp/`;
cp -r /storage/brno2/home/nicki/snp/(!input) .
```

Thanks to echo I can see that folder named "input" is in folder where I expect it to be. However, it seems that extglob is not working for me :(

```
/var/spool/torque/mom_priv/jobs/2308017.arien.ics.muni.cz.SC: line 11: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/var/spool/torque/mom_priv/jobs/2308017.arien.ics.muni.cz.SC: line 11: `cp -r /storage/brno2/home/nicki/snp/(!input) .'
```

I can of course list all files I want to copy. Still, I would like to avoid such nasty practice..

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct syntax for extended globs is

```
!(pattern-list)
```

The exclamation mark should go outside the parentheses.